# Error creating a site from a template in SP2010

Tags: site-template

I can create a site template without any problems and it will happily sit in the solution gallery all activated and nice looking. 
When I then try to create a new site and pick that template I get this error.
The content type name '$Resources:DataSourceContentTypeName;' cannot contain: \ / : ? etc....

[alt text http://arts.twynhamschool.com/templateerror.png](http://arts.twynhamschool.com/templateerror.png)

Just to be clear I've not used any of those illegal characters anywhere.
Anyone seen this before or shed any light?
All ideas welcome as I've tried many things already.

Chris.

Comment: Have you looked that correlation id up in the ULS log?  This might give you more info on what is happening.

Comment: Also plz supply the language pack you are running with, since ressource files are invoved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an upgraded farm? if so sometimes the content types fail on upgrade (specially for reporting services).
If you go to content site content types you can see that the some of the content types are not getting their names from the resource file (eg: $Resources:Data......)

The way we solved this was by forcing to uninstall the reporting feature using http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/ (you can also use stsadm -force for this) and then actviate the reporting feature again from site collection feature.

Hope this helps

UPDATE:
After doing this you will need to create the template again

Comment: It looks as if you've cracked it. I will try your solution and let you know.

Comment: Yes we had the same problem the other day (hence the update:))